# Sending a few php variables in email triggered by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

i want to send a few php variables by a trigger from javascript. The variables, databases and the script is working but i cant figure our the PHP part.

This is what I think the PHP should be like but its obviously faulit. i just want to send the few variables.

```
if{
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = "host";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );

    $mail->setFrom('noreply', 'hint');
    $mail->addAddress('email.test.com');

    $mail->Subject = 'hint';
    $msg='Allikas: '.$_POST['source']
    $mail->msgHTML('<strong>Hint.</strong>;
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'ERROR';
        //return false;
        //echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
}else{echo "SUCCESS";}
```

}

This is my javascript trigger

```
        else if (checked === true) {
        console.log("asddd")
        "send the stuff (part i need help with")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an ajax request

```
var values = {"source":"the source...", "location":"the location..."}; // add your others variable here...
$.ajax({
        url: "yourphpfile.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values ,
        success: function (response) {
           // it will return the result (SUCCESS or ERROR)  

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```